# Calling setContentRotation by 90 degrees on IconGenerator shows inconsitent apperance with extra padding and clipping of contents

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

im trying to display a marker with custom content view, to the right hand side of the map location. Im using android google map utility library to create a marker icon from custom content view using the icongenerator class.

As suggested in [documentation](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/), the correct way to get the marker to right hand side of the location is acheived by calling setRotation(90) and setContentRotition(-90) on icongenerator object before making icon from it.  But the problem i see that when ever setContentRotation is called with 90 degree roation (+/-), there is some extra padding and clipping of contents being observed in the marker icon that is generated. to give a glimpse of the issue the following [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9MfG.jpg) captures the maker with different rotation values for marker and the contained content view

im not sure if there is something Im doing wrong or an issue with library . I logged a git issue for the library and comments are awaited.

Im sure some of us might have encountered this issue. Hope to see some suggestions towards the same..